# Python, How to invoke an instance method from inside a another Class

Tags: python

I have a Python GUI with a Frame that has one upperpanel and a vertical splitterwindow. For each  Panel in the splitterwindow I created two Panel classes, one with a listbox and the other one with a grid. Each class has several buttons.

Is there is a way to keep the button connect `event.bind` and function code inside the class and make it work, because, presently I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Panel' object has no attribute 'm_dirPicker1'
```

I would like to know which is the best practice in the reported situation.

This is an example a short example of what I have wrote:

```
class Frame ( wx.Frame ):
    ...
    self.m_datapanel = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    self.m_filespanel = Source_Panel( self.m_splitter1)
    self.m_gridpanel = Data_Viewer( self.m_splitter1)

class Source_Panel ( wx.Panel ):
    ...

        # Connect Events
        self.m_listBox.Bind( wx.EVT_LISTBOX_DCLICK, self.m_listBoxOnListBoxDClick )
        self.m_clearbutton.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.m_clearbuttonOnButtonClick )
        self.m_importbutton.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.m_importbuttonOnButtonClick )
        self.m_showdata.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.m_showdataOnButtonClick )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def m_listBoxOnListBoxDClick( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def m_clearbuttonOnButtonClick( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def m_importbuttonOnButtonClick( self, event ):
        src_directory = frame.m_datapanel.m_dirPicker1.GetTextCtrlValue()

    def m_showdataOnButtonClick( self, event ):
        event.Skip()


class Data_Viewer ( wx.Panel ):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that your `Source_Panel` instance will be a child of a `MyFrame` instance (I'm going to refer to your `Frame` as `MyFrame` to avoid confusion with the `wx.Frame` base class).

In that case, the `Parent` attribute of your `Source_Panel` instance should refer to the parent `MyFrame`.

Then you can just call:

```
self.Parent.m_datapanel.m_dirPicker1.GetTextCtrlValue()
```

Comment: You're right. Thank you for your help. I was looking another topic when I read something helpfull. I can also use: self.m_frame = Frame(None) and then src_directory = self.m_frame.m_dirPicker1.GetTextCtrlValue().Wich i see that is exactly the same that you've wrote... Kind regards.Ivo

Comment: great, just note that since you're subclassing `wx.Panel`, the `self.Parent` attribute should already exist after you instantiate a `Source_Panel` - you don't need to assign the new attribute `self.m_frame`.

Comment: Later I inserted SourcePanel and ViewerPanel in a WxSplitter so I changed my code to self.GrandParent.m_dirPicker1.GetTextCtrlValue() and it works fine. Kind Regards. Ivo